# Error in Bubble sort. Getting an input wrong

Tags: c, sorting

I have the following source and when I execute it the values are getting their signs changed. I am not able to find out where I am going wrong. Any suggestions is helpful

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int arrsort(int *arr, int size);
int display(int *arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int s_o_1=0, s_o_2=0;
    int i; //index for arrays
    int a[s_o_1],b[s_o_2];


    printf("enter the size of the first array\n");
    scanf("%d",&s_o_1);

    printf("Enter the values of the first array\n");
    for (i=0;i<s_o_1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    printf("enter the size of the second array\n");
    scanf("%d",&s_o_2);

    printf("Enter the values of the second array\n");
    for (i=0;i<s_o_2;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }

    //sort the first array

    arrsort(a,s_o_1);
    printf("The sorted first array is\n");
    display(a,s_o_1);

    //sort the second array

    arrsort(b,s_o_2);
    printf("The sorted second array is\n");
    display(b,s_o_2);

}

int arrsort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int temp; //for holding the temp value
    int i; //for indexing
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
            }
        }   
    }
}



int display(int *arr, int size)
{
    int i; //array index
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",i);

    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
enter the size of the first array
5
Enter the values of the first array
1 5 -10 -15 3
enter the size of the second array
5
Enter the values of the second array
-3 -5 15 9 10
The sorted first array is
0   1   2   3   4   
-15 -10 3   5   10  
The sorted second array is
0   1   2   3   4   
-15 -10 -5  -3  9
```

Comment: @AntoineMathys Can you please help me identify it..

Comment: @AntoineMathys figured it finally..thanks for noticing it out..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the array declaration:

```
int s_o_1=0, s_o_2=0;
int i; //index for arrays
int a[s_o_1],b[s_o_2];
```

The arrays are probably declared with size 0. Either declare with an appropriate maximum size, or declare after reading the sizes for the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behaviour. In this line:

```
int a[s_o_1],b[s_o_2];
```

It declares arrays with zero size. When later get values for s_o_1 and s_o_2 the array size won't change. So all your reads & writes lead to undefined behaviour.

C standard requires array should be of non-zero length.

Answer (score 1):

The way you reserve memory is not correct `int a[s_o_1],b[s_o_2];`

You  must use `int *a, *b;` and later after `scanf("%d",&s_o_1);` you need to do something like `a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*s_o_1);`
The same goes to allocating memory for b.

Also bubble sort alghorithm should be something like bellow

```
 for(j=0;j<size - 1;j++)
    {
        for(i=j + 1;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }   
    }
```